# Adding Space in front line after subsection in Latex

Tags: latex, texstudio

I want to add a space in front of Fatality Rate just like the Log transformation in the picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzTpD.png)

Here is my Latex Code

```
\subsection*{Data}  
    Fatality Rate: \[ \frac{\mbox{Total Death Number}}{\mbox{Total Case Number}} \]
    
    Log Transformation: \[\log_{} \frac{\mbox{Infection Rate}}{1-\mbox{Infection Rate}} \]
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? That will be very helpful!

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre], not just a code fragment

Answer (score -1):

just use `\hspace{1em}` at the start of a line where you want an indentation.